# PHP Code insert values but when called with function the result is diffrent

Tags: php, arrays, function

im trying to execute code by calling function but the result is different from executing the code by itself

```
$arr1=array(
0 => array(
"id" => 5,
"SKS" => 2,
"assignStatus" => 0
)

);

$arr2=array(
    0 => array(//hari senin
        0 => array(//sesi 1
            0 => array( //ruang 405
                0 => "", //draft 
                1 => "",  //sks
                2 => 0   //count3sks
            )       
        )
    )
);

//execute code with function
assignNilai($arr2,0,0,0,$arr1,0);
echo $arr2[0][0][0][0]." ".$arr2[0][0][0][1]." ".$arr2[0][0][0][2];
echo "<br>";
//execute code without function
$arr2[0][0][0][0] = $arr1[0]['id'];
 $arr2[0][0][0][1] = $arr1[0]['SKS'];
  if ($arr2[0][0][0][1]==3) {
    $arr2[0][0][0][2] = $csp[0][0][0][2] + 1; 
  }

echo $arr2[0][0][0][0]." ".$arr2[0][0][0][1]." ".$arr2[0][0][0][2];

function assignNilai($arr2,$hari,$sesi,$ruang,$arr1,$draft){
  $arr2[$hari][$sesi][$ruang][0] = $arr1[$draft]['id'];
  $arr2[$hari][$sesi][$ruang][1] = $arr1[$draft]['SKS'];
   if ($arr2[$hari][$sesi][$ruang][1]==3) {
      $arr2[$hari][$sesi][$ruang][2] = $csp[$hari][$sesi][$ruang][2] + 1; 
  }
}
```

im trying to achieve what displayed on the manually executed code using function, how to do it?

Comment: what is the result you are getting and what is your expected result ?

Comment: the result when executed with function is 0

my expected result is the $arr2 to be filled with  arr1's id and sks, and if the sks is 3, the value of count3sks inside $arr2 will be +1 if the sks is 3 

it would look like this: 
$arr2 [0][0][0][0] = 5,$arr2 [0][0][0][1] = 2,$arr2 [0][0][0][2] = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the scope of data, you need to pass the data into the function be reference (use &) to your function to allow the function to alter the original array rather than a local copy of the data...

```
function assignNilai(&$arr2,$hari,$sesi,$ruang,$arr1,$draft){
```

The `&$arr2` bit allows the function to modify your original array.

In your original code, the function was working with it's own version of the array, so when the function finished, this version was just discarded and the original value of the array was still the same.

Comment: so what i was lacking is a way to modify the original array with the value of local array within the function, and using the & on the $arr2 argument enables that?

Comment: If you echoed your array in the function at the end, you would get the values you wanted.  But in the scope where you call the function, these changes are not made.  When you use &, this effectively means that you are working with the same set of values.